# fprintf segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

```
  char* output= (char*) argv[2];
 92     fp = fopen(output, "w");
 93     if( fp = NULL )
 94     {
 95         printf("writing output failed");
 96         return 0;
 97     }
 98     fprintf(fp,"hello");
```

This is causing seg fault exc bad memory at line 98.
What am I missing??

Comment: can you accept answers to questions that you have found useful, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line 93

`if( fp = NULL )`

is assigning fp to NULL rather than comparing it to NULL.  Use

`if( fp == NULL )`

instead.

As netcoder pointed out, your compiler should warn you about this.  You could also write your test in the form `if (NULL == fp)` to generate a compiler error if you accidentally swap comparison for assignment.  (Note that some people may find this style of coding distasteful so it may generate some complaints in code reviews!)

Answer (score 8):

Your line

```
if( fp = NULL)
```

is assigning the value of `NULL` to `fp`, instead of comparing.

You should be using

```
if( fp == NULL)
```

Comment: Both GCC and MSVC should warn you about these, if warnings are enabled of course.

Comment: @netcoder: good point; also `lint` will help you find issues like this too.